# install binary file != move binary to path folder?

Tags: command-line, install

What is the difference (is there any?) between `sudo install -c -o %username% binaryfile usr/local/bin` and just moving binary file to `usr/local/bin`?

Comment: Read the man page for [`install`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/install.1.html)!

Comment: What Mac model and OS version are you doing this on?  What directory are you in when you run the command? Did you really want to install into `usr/local/bin` and not `/usr/local/bin` with the preceding `/`?  Does the directory exist on the computer?

Answer (score 1):

When you use `install`, it will copy a file to it's destination, while `mv` changes the directory listing and is atomic. When you move a file from one file system to another then `mv` is not atomic and will copy the file to the other file system then remove the source file. Obviously, `mv` and `install` have different options with `install` offering you more fine grain choices.

Comment: Could you please explain the use of the word "atomic" in your answer?

Comment: @user3439894- atomic in the context that if the user has the proper access to the source and destination, the operation can not be interrupted. Thus the operation is guaranteed. I 'm burning in a new computer and don't have access to all the man pages yet, but I think that rename(2)  and atomic(3) contain information.